# Pasting SO search links with explicit tags into comments does not work as expected

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, comments

See [StackOverflow question "Object Oriented pattern in C ?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201521/object-oriented-pattern-in-c). When trying to paste a link to [a stackoverflow seach that might have helped](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c]+object+orientation) the asker, I discovered that the comment formater can't handle URLs with '[' in them. Possibly other characters are affected as well.

Comment: Sadly, in the very example you posted, there is a comment with `+` inside the url working perfectly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5D+object+orientation

Comment: Ah...it wasn't the '+' but the '['...mea culpa

Comment: @Kyle Cronin: Nice. Working. But I don't want to have to translate html entities...

Comment: Wait. Did you just paste that? What browser? I'm using Firefox 3.0.12 on Mac OS.

Comment: @dmckee: I just copied the link in question from your question and pasted it into a comment. It appears that the Markdown (or whatever) auto-escapes the [ and ] in the link.

Comment: Odd. The one I was complaining about got there after I copied it from the address bar, and pasted into a comment. I wonder what controls it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said you don't want to have to encode the URL, but there isn't really a way around that.  The problem is that `[` and `]` are characters used for signifying links in Markdown.  Sure, it could technically ignore `[` within a link, but it certainly can't ignore `]`.  And don't even suggest that it detect pairs of `[` and `]`; this is a [bad idea with regex](http://welbog.homeip.net/glue/53/XML-is-not-regular).

Comment: Ah. Not east to fix then. Thanks.

Comment: Now you're linking to my site too!? Why not just change your name to Welbog?

Comment: it is fixed. We force-encode () and [] now